# How to made unclickable area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you help me plaese!

I had to use next jQuery functionality.

```
elem.parents('.CanvasRoot:first').unbind('click').click(function(){
...
}

<div class="CanvasRoot">
...
</div>
```

But now, I should add area inside the current div. And I don't need to that area called click js function.

```
<div class="CanvasRoot">
<table class="notForClick">
</table>
</div>
```

How can I prevent that area from clicking?

Thanks!

Comment: Click events bubble. Can't you just capture the click on an appropriate element and stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".notForClick").click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div onClick="return false;">
Hi this is an unclickable area..
It will not respond to ur click's
</div>
```

<-- Using Jquery-->

```
<div id="unclick">
Hi unclickable...
</div>

$("#unclick").on('click',function(){return false;})
```